# create session and then destroy on ajax form submit

Tags: jquery, forms, session

I have a form on a site (built on wordpress), I am working on. Here is an step by step illustration of what I am trying to achieve.

The visitor :

1. Hits the submit button.
2. On successful submission he is redirected to another page.
3. Hits the back button (for any stupid reason whatsoever).
4. He gets "Document Expired" page (in Firefox and may be differ for every other browser).

For this I am trying to use sessions of which I do not know enough about. I have put `session_start();` at the very top of the page before the header and here comes the issue. No matter where I put the `session_destroy();` I cannot get the desired result. If I will need to assign variables how would I do it. Kindly help. Below are the snippets I use.

**HTML** - This one is a bit crazy as it does not use `<form>` tag and delivers the content which is generated within the div.

```
    <div id="content-div">
    //some php generated contents
    </div>

<input type="submit" value="SUBMIT CONTENT" id="short_button" onClick="handleFormSubmit()">
```

**AJAX** - For submit and redirect

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
             function handleFormSubmit(){
             var button = document.getElementById('short_button');
                button.style.display = 'none';
                    }
        </script>

        <script type="text/javascript">
            jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
               $('#short_button').click(function(){
                    $.ajax({
                    type: 'POST',
                    url: 'http://awesomeness.com/pathto/processForm.php',
                    data:{'message':$('#content-div').html(),'client': $('#some-field').val() },
                    success:function(data) {
                    window.location = "http://awesomeness.com/thanks/";
                                 }
                });
                    });
                });

        </script>
```

**PROCESSFORM.PHP**

```
$to = "emailto@awesomepeople.com";
  $subject  = "NEW ARTICLE";
  $message .= $_POST['message'];
  $client   = $_POST ['client'];
  $headers = "From: awesomesite <someone@website.com>" . "\r\n";
  $headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
  $headers .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1\r\n";           
  mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
```

Bottomline :  where do I put the `session_destroy();` code to get the desired result as illustrated in step 4. In other words how do I destroy the session once the form is submit. If I need to use session variables like `$_SESSION=['input']` then how do I use it in this situation. Many thanks in advance.

Comment: i'm no php expert... but... shouldn't you have to generate that "Document Expired" message yourself?

Comment: In another form which is completely built on php I receive the "Document Expired" on firefox once I hit the back button after submit and it kind of resets the form. This message will be different in every browser I guess.

Comment: I see. I don't think your sessions has anything to do with this at all. is the other form that's working correctly not using window.location to redirecT?

Comment: Why do you not simply POST the form in a traditional, non-AJAX way, if your desire is to actually load a different page? Hitting the back button back to the original page is not going to work for you, as as far as the browser is concerned, that page which holds the form did not actually have a form POST since the POST was handled asynchronously.

Comment: I have put the question in right order and made it pretty explicit, hope it makes sense now. Please take a look again.

Comment: are you trying to mimic the `Post-Redirect-Get` pattern?  You want #4 to happen, right?  But it's not?  What is actually happening?

Comment: @gloomy.penguin dunno abt Post-Redirect-Get, but yes I want the #4 to happen and right now when I submit and hit back button I get the same page that I submitted instead of the "session expired" page.

Comment: why do you want their session to expire if they hit the back button...?  or you just want them to not go back to the form page? what is your actual goal or what are you trying to avoid/stop and why?

Comment: I simply want them not to go back to page and resubmit. How do I do that ?